# DragDrop application goes wrong when changing screen size

Tags: android

I am making a small application on android, it is based on dragdrop with shadowbuilder, i used an emulator with screen wvga800 (800x480), it was working fine, when draging an element to a grid it drops properly in the destination grid.
Then i used another emulator with screen wxga800-7in (1280-800), it went all wrong,
the elements dont drop anymore inside the grid, they appear to shift to another position.
note: in the layout XML file the used unit is dp.
What is excactly the problem here? please help.

Thanks in advance for any help.

The following are the code for touch listener and drag listener :

```
 private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);              
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view,0);
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;}
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }//class MyTouchListener


class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {
        Drawable enterShapeAcp = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_droptargetacp);
        Drawable enterShapeRej= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_droptargetrej);
        Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
           // int action = event.getAction();
            switch (event.getAction()) {

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:{
                break;}

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:{
                grid(v.getX(),v.getY());
                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(enterShapeAcp);

                break;}

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:{
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                break;}

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:{
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();

                    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                    owner.removeView(view);
                    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
                    container.addView(view);
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                 break;}

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:{
               v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
               break;}   

            default:{
                 break;}
             }//switch

            return true;

        }//onDrag
    }//class MyDragListener
```

Comment: Some code will help better understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `LinearLayout` has proper Orientation? If not it may scale unexpectedly and provide weird results.

**EDIT:** If you are familiar with debugging it will help you a lot to understand which grid element is receiving the view and what went wrong. Give some time to it with both emulators and figure out the difference.

Comment: Yes, there is no problem with the linearLayout,
the problem is appearing that the shadowbuilder is considering the screen as 800x480, it is also making the object smaller.

Comment: onProvideShadowMetrics(android.graphics.Point, android.graphics.Point) can be used to solve the size issue. By default it produces a shadow hich is slightly smaller from what i have seen. The shadow Builder just creates the shadow, it has nothing to do with considering the resolution or something. That problem lies in your grid.

Comment: I tried to use onProvideShadowMetrics() , but didnt even change the size of the shadow.
what would be the problem with the grid?

Comment: iam using NetBeans IDE , i have never used Eclipse before, so ,is there any difference between them ?

Comment: as long as you can access the debug perspective, no problem at all.